# Convert 2D ArrayList of Integers to multiple ArrayLists of Integers?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have a 2D ArrayList:

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

And I want to go through a for loop and convert each line of the list to a new ArrayList:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        ArrayList<Integer> element = list.get(i);
}
```

This spits out the error

> incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.util.ArrayList

I don't use 2D ArrayLists very often. Say my list is

```
[[1, 2, 3], [0, 5], [-2], [2, 3, 1]]
```

How can I assign each block to an ArrayList? I want to first have an ArrayList that is [1, 2, 3], send it to a function, then rinse and repeat for the rest of the list.

Answer (score 2):

`get()` method always return object of type `Object` class. You have to downcast it :

```
ArrayList<Integer> element = ( ArrayList<Integer>)list.get(i);
```

Comment: I get a Warning: Warning: unchecked cast
  required: java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Integer>
  found:    java.lang.Object

Comment: Is that really a problem?

Comment: Nevermind this seems to have fixed it .Thank you very much!

Comment: You're getting warnings because what you're doing can't be proved to be safe. But this is not an issue.. You can sue this :
`@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`